# Possible to run asp net web form portable? Or create an installer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is it possible to run asp net web form portable? Or create an installer? I made an web site on asp net web forms and i need to deploy it together with an app that i already made. Is it possible to run it without having to manualy configure all iis stuff?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to [create a deployment package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465323(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Web Deployment Package only works with iis enabled, right?

Comment: As far as I know WebForms will only run in IIS so there is no getting around that.

Comment: Impossible to be portable if you stick to IIS. Third party options are out there like http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/Default.aspx If you go with an installer, then you can automate IIS installation and configuration from there. Examples for more specific installer technologies can be found via search engines as people discussed for decades.

Comment: And what about the database part? As noted you could try and install IIS, but that's a huge job and setup of IIS can take a good day or so to get up and running. So, as noted you really do need a server running IIS. And as noted you probably need a database system to be installed and setup also.

Comment: database is handled by the other app that i built.